# When trying to include '#include <boost/regex.hpp>' I get: 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_39.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-regex

Not sure why i get that, I downloaded libs from [here](http://www.boostpro.com/download) and while I have a lib called 'libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_39.lib I don't have one which is called 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_39.lib', renaming the one with vc90 to vc100 works but I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  boost::array<int, 10> a;
  boost::smatch s;

  getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using Visual Studio 2010 (this is where vc100 comes from), but the downloaded lib was built with 2008 (vc9)

Visual Studio 2010 comes with TR1, include `<regex>` and enjoy.