# Adding C++ Boost binaries to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

I know there are several threads where people ask this question, and for that I apologize. I've spent a fair amount of time reading them, testing, doing more research, and failing.

I can get header-only libraries to work. Once I try to link to a library, such as regex, I get the error "LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc110-mt-gd-1_58.lib'." I followed the directions on the Boost website to compile the binaries, and the file definitely exists. I've tried a bunch of options when building them, including using the --build-type=complete, which creates several versions of the binary file.

As for include directories, this is what I have: "C:\boost\boost_1_58_0; C:\boost\boost_1_58_0\stage\lib". "Stage\lib" is where the binary files are located.

Thank you for any help anyone can provide. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738089/when-trying-to-include-include-boost-regex-hpp-i-get-1link-fatal-error?rq=1 You might be using deprecated libraries?

Comment: Thank you both. I had to put the path to the regex library in a different location.